# How do I remove the "Set as StartUp Object" designation on an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

It's easy to right-click and set a package as the startup object in an SSIS 2005 solution.
[image: Set as StartUp Object]

When it comes to removing that option, I could find nothing.  There were dozens of pages on adding it, but nothing on removing it.  After poking around all afternoon, I found that if I go to the "XXXXX.dtproj.user" file in the main solution folder, I can remove the "StartObjectID" tag in a text editor to accomplish this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataTransformationsUserConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Configurations>
    <Configuration>
      <Name>Whatever</Name>
      <Options>
        <StartObjectID>Whatever.dtsx</StartObjectID>
        <UserIDs />
        <UserPasswords />
        <OfflineMode>false</OfflineMode>
      </Options>
    </Configuration>
  </Configurations>
</DataTransformationsUserConfiguration>
```

Is there a more obvious way to remove "Set as StartUp Object" from an SSIS package?

Comment: There has to be Something marked as the startup object, so you can set something ELSE to the startup object, but you can't "unset" it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click solution folder ---> Configuration Properties---> Debugging----->Start Action

Set the start object id to  **Active Package**

Comment: Perfect!  Just to clarify, I right clicked the top node in the Solution Explorer, chose properties, then followed your directions.  [This image demonstrates it.](http://i.imgur.com/Cx6QIoS.jpg)